# Best practice to send reports via external email (SSRS, CRM or other means)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, salesforce, crm, hubspot

We want to start sending out emails to our customers that has tracking information attached. I've done this internally with a data driven subscription but I'm sure that isn't an industry best practice for sending externally.

I know this could cause some issues with spam filtering, etc...

How have you handled this before? We wouldn't be sending more than 30-50 per day initially, but as the business grows so will those numbers. I'm sure there's a service where we send the data and they would send on our behalf, but I'm pretty unfamiliar with how this is done industry wide.

Do people use their CRM's marketing platforms to take care of something like this?

Answer (score 0):

SSRS reports are usually for internal staff and a CRM or dedicated tool (like MailChimp, SendInBlue or MailerLite) is used for sending mailshots to customers externally.  I have known some organisations use SSRS for sending externally, but that's not what it was intended for - and it is probably a security risk to let the internal production SQL Server access the internet directly.